# I need help identifying an SMD DFN/SON IC marked 8211 and D4

Tags: battery-charging, identification, surface-mount

I need help identifying an IC. These are used for lithium-!ion battery charging/protection.

The SMD IC marked 8211 is a battery protection IC (MOSFET). I was able to find out from the circuit that the bottom pad is drain, 1, 2 is source, 5, 6 is source, 3, 4 is gate which is controlled by the IC marked D4 GK. I am not able to identify these SMD parts.

Mark in SMD IC (small one with mark D4 or DA) is not clear.

[image: SMD IC 8211]

[image: SMD IC Mark: D4 GK]

[image: SMD IC Mark: D4]

Comment: It's the other out-of-focus marking that is important.

Comment: Marking is not clear, its D4 and GK (below)

Comment: maybe it is not a  `4` ... the horizontal line is at an angle ... it could be a logo

Comment: Yes, possible its delta symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D4
R5480K260CL
Nisshinbo R5480K Series

[image]

Comment: ZendX - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. I agree that the [R5480K](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/792/r5480-ea-1770670.pdf) is the type of Li-ion battery protection IC that would fit as a possible identification of that IC marked D4 GK. However in the R5480K datasheet, I couldn't find any listing of the possible top markings to confirm that those codes are for that *specific* IC. Do you have a link or other reference to confirm the identification with those top codes? You can always [edit] your answer to add references. Thanks.

Comment: Thank You, I ordered similar product from ABLIC- S-82A1A series , same pinouts..

Answer (score 0):

Product from Ablic: S-82A1A Series

[image: ABLIC - S-82A1A]